# Define reference name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-generate

Is there a way to define reference name with "rails generate" command?

There is table A with two fields - a1 and a2: references to table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main principles of rails is "convention over configuration". It works great for cases like this:

```
 rails generate model Player team:references
```

This will create column `team_id` and mark it as foreign key to table `teams`.

This covers 90% of all possible needs (*educated guesstimate*). If you have a "standard" model, you'll generate the boilerplate for it in seconds. But if you have a more exotic case (like the one in the question), then you'll have to do a bit of manual work and touch migration file and model relation definitions yourself. Which is quite easy as well.

```
t.references :a1, references: :b
t.references :a2, references: :b
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, I need to know if I can avoid manual editing migration files or writing some workaround.

Comment: @ar7max I think I have answered that. Your relations are "unconventional", and so you get less hand-holding from rails.